# Yii order by another table with has_many relation

Tags: yii, has-many

I have this Object model with 'has_many' relation to Variables

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'variables' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Variables', 'variable_id')
    );
}
```

Now i want to use the variables to order my data like

```
$criteria->with = array('variables');

$criteria->order = 'variables.id DESC';
```

But it doesn't work.

Is there a way to do something like this? Thanks.

Comment: add your full code of controller function

Comment: sorry what do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

You can define the relation directly with an order if you want, in this case you can do.

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'variables' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Variables', 'object_id', 'order'=>'variables.id DESC')
    );
}
```

What you wrote it is not working because you have a 1 to many relation. The criteria will run 2 queries, 1 to get the main record, the second time to get the relations. That is why your order is not working.
If you want it to work like you said you should do a ->join instead of ->with.
There is quite a difference between the 2 so take care how you are writing the criteria.

Comment: i try your suggestion but it says that:  Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "variables"

Comment: if you tried the relations one, then you should not use "$criteria->order = 'variables.id DESC';". Just read the main record in any way you need to then do
foreach($model->variables as $variable) {}
the variables will be ordered already.

Comment: sorry for the late response, so basically there's no other way than that? i am using my model as dataProvider, how would i use/integrate in the foreach?

Comment: Well, actually I think this is the answer you are looking for:  
$item = Something::model()->with(array('relationname'=>array('order'=>'relationname.id ASC')))
        ->findByPk($id);

Or   
  
$items = Something::model()->with(array('relationname'=>array('order'=>'relationname.id ASC')))
        ->findAll(...);

Comment: I am using another model which extends to the one that is generated by gii. My problem is that I wasn't able to do order it by the relation. In my controller, I generate my dataProvider by something like this $data = MyModel::getList($filters); I hope I am able to explain my side.

Comment: There is no getList function in Yii from what I know.

Comment: getList is a function I have made.

Comment: I am not sure what you expect mate, I gave you 3 ways to perform what you desire. Now you bring in another function that I have no idea about and give it as an example. What exactly do you want as an answer?

Comment: sorry for the troubles but i somehow solve it by just using the other Model so that their relationship would be 'Belongs to'

Comment: You will see in time that something else fixed it, that should have no impact on what you want. Anyway cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with foreign key binding, if you are adding a relationship in object table (Object model) which has many variables having object_id as foreign key in variable table (Variable model) then you need to define relationship as follows:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'variables' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Variables', 'object_id') // check the change in foreign key column
    );
}
```